# how to remove specific numbers from a for loop in js

Tags: javascript, indexof, splice

I'm trying too fix the problem I made a for loop that goes from 1 to 100. And I want too remove everything that haves 6 in it.

This is my code

```js
var myarray = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        myarray.push(i);       
    }
console.log(...myarray);

for (var i = 1; i < myarray.length; i++){ 
           if ( myarray.indexOf(6)) {           
               myarray.splice(i, 1); 
             } else {
              ++i
             }
           }
console.log(...myarray);
```

And this didn't work it will only remove the first 6, could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: `const newArray = myarray.filter(x => !x.toString().includes('6'));` ?

Comment: Are you allowed to use string functions or IS THIS A MATH PROBLEM?

Comment: yes, Im allowed to use string functions. its more of a open project to improve my js skills, and this is one part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert each number to a string and check if it contains `6` :

```js
var myarray = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if(!i.toString().includes('6')) {
    myarray.push(i);
  } else {
    console.log("skip " + i);
  }
}

console.log(myarray);
```

Note that you could remove the `else` clause, I've added it to show that we skip the numbers containing a `6`.

Comment: I would honestly prefer to use `.toString()` method over the `+""` implicit coercion. It's esoteric & not as clear.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli I updated my answer so that it is clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom, I can go further with this information

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (to create a new, fitered Array) and [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) (to filter out integers which string representation includes the character `"6"`)

```js
const myarray = Array.from(Array(100), (_, i) => i+1);
const result = myarray.filter(n => !`${n}`.includes("6"));

console.log(result);
```